# What exactly do we call "Poisson's semigroup" in Fourier analysis?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I saw in my lectures notes on Fourier analysis that we call "Poisson's semigroup" the following observations :

Let $\alpha>0$ and $f(x) = \exp(-\alpha \vert x \vert)$. We started by computing $\widehat f$, then using the inversion theorem we deduced the Fourier transform of $x\mapsto \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$. Moreover we did the Fourier transform of $x\mapsto \dfrac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$ (using convolution) and finally we computed the Fourier transform of $x\mapsto \dfrac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}$ (using derivatives).

After all of this, I could not figure out why it is called "Poisson's semigroup" and the link with the observations and also what is its use. Did anyone has more precise references about it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: For $a \ge 0$ let $T_a$ be the bounded linear map $L^2(\Bbb{R})\to L^2(\Bbb{R})$ given by $T_av (x)=\exp(-a|x|)v(x)$. It is a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup), we have $T_a \circ T_b = T_{a+b}$. Taking its Fourier transform (ie. the operator such that $S_a\widehat{v}=\widehat{T_a v}$) you get another semigroup whose elements are given by convolutions with $L^1$ functions.

Comment: @reuns Ok thank you for the precisions !